# SSRS ReportViewer Design breaks in first and last page and flickering issue in pagination

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am using Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms for viewing SSRS reports in aspx page facing following issues

1. In first page previous page buttons are misaligned

[image]

2. In last page next page buttons are misaligned.

[image]

3. Flickering issue while pagination.

While clicking on next/ previous buttons are misaligned.

[image]

Once load completes controls are getting aligned.
[image]

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms version – 150.1449.0

[image]

So can anyone please help me resolve this issues.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is more of a bug report than a question that could be answered here.